# Git Branch Changes Doesn't Show outside Master

Tags: git

I am fairly new to git.  I created a branch.  That branch shows up in BitBucket, where the remote repo resides.  But shouldn't I be seeing a separate development path for my changes?  My changes seem to be on the main line.

Below on the right you can see my branch tag for each check-in.

[image]

Comment: How are you merging, pushing? How did you create your local branch? Actual branch names would be helpful in answering your question. Running `git remote show origin` locally would be helpful.

Comment: Since you are new to Git, check out [Git for Ages 4 and Up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3m7BgIvC-uQ). The speaker uses an old school Connector Set to visualize Git commits and branches, which was brilliant.

Comment: Did you just *create* a branch (i.e. `git branch foo`), or did you actually *switch to* that branch (`git checkout foo`, or `git checkout -b foo master`)? If you didn't switch to the new branch, then you're still committing on `master`. The output of `git branch` or `git status` will indicate what branch you are on...

Comment: hmm maybe that's what happened I didn't checkout the branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But shouldn't I be seeing a separate development path for my changes?

Yes, your changes are in a different branch.  Git isn't displaying it as you'd expect with a visual branch.

You're expecting something like this...

```
o [mybranch]
|
o
|
o
 \
  o [master]
  |
```

But BitBucket has shown you this.

```
o [mybranch]
|
o
|
o
|
o [master]
|
```

If there's no divergent changes between `master` and `mybranch`, Git will not do anything special.  If someone put a commit on `master`, then you'd see a branch.

```
o [mybranch]
|
o
|
o o [master]
 \|
  o
  |
```

This might seem weird, but it makes sense in how Git branches work.  Branches aren't really branches, they're just labels on commits.  If the commit doesn't have two parents, it won't bother to display a kink in the graph.

This might seem academic, but it becomes very important to understanding how things like fast-forwards, merges and rebase work in Git.  For example, were you to merge `mybranch` into `master`, Git wouldn't do a merge; it would move the `master` branch to the same commit as `mybranch`.  This is known as a fast-forward.

```
o [mybranch] [master]
|
o
|
o
|
o
|
```

Comment: I'd actually expect to see the flip of that first where master is the mainline and branches come off off that to the right

Comment: @WeDoTDD That's a common expectation. `master` has no special status. It is the name of the first branch when a repository is created. Similarly `origin` has no special status. It is the default name for the remote repository when cloning. Most history displays will keep the newest branch the straightest.

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely hard to get used to the "one-dimensional" view of branch logs.  If you open up Git Bash (locally), run the following command in your repository:

```
$ git branch -vv
```

You should see the difference branches and their last commits (as well as the commit message).  That'll give you proof/verification that each branch is at a different commit.

Also, a surprisingly good GUI at looking at this is `gitk`:

```
$ gitk --all
```

For me, that graphic is a little easier to visualize the branching.

It's hard to see in that image on bitbucket, but there is a little indentation from your branch.  If you had commits on the `master` branch after you created your previous branch, it would be more evident on the more dramatic branching, as the `master` branch would then have commits that aren't in your other branch.

Comment: @WeDoTDD No problem, glad to help!